# What is the sign of $4+16\left(-3+4p^2\right)\left(p^4+3p^2-1\right)$ where $p\in[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis

We consider $$\Delta=4+16\left(-3+4p^2\right)\left(p^4+3p^2-1\right)$$ with $p$ is a parameter which satisfies $p\in[0,1].$

I want to study the sign of $\Delta$.

Please help me.

Comment: Is 'discute' a typo for 'discern'? If you plot $\Delta$ you'll see it changes sign over the interval you mention.

Comment: @ diracula i don't sea that clearly how $\Delta$ changes sign over the interval $[0,1]$,       @postmortes, $\left(-3+4p^2\right)=0$ iff $p=\sqrt{3/4}$ and $\left(p^4+3p^2-1\right)>0$ for all $p\in[0,1]$ what i don't know how to conclude?

Comment: $\Delta = 52$ if $p=0$ or $p=1$. $\Delta = -4652/729$ if $p=2/3$. What have you tried to study the sign?

Answer (score 1):

1. Polynomials are continuous functions.
2. $$p(0) = 52$$
3. $$p(-1) = -44$$

As noted by @Saketh Malyala, the intermediate value theorem reveals we have at least one root in the interval $(0,1)$.

[image: poly]

Comment: good use of IVT! +1